# Apt-cacher and Apt-proxy

Tags: ubuntu, debian

Does anyone know the differences between apt-proxy and apt-cacher or know of a better package proxy cacher for Ubuntu?  I used apt-proxy, but it hangs in weird places and gives me weird errors sometimes.  It is written in python, Apt-cacher is Perl but seems to be more stable, but slower on updates.  Anyone with other experience?

Comment: My experience mirrors your own.  apt-proxy is somewhat buggy and hangs.  Apt-cacher seems to be slower.  I am almost the point that I was thinking it would be easier to just mirror the entire x86 portion of the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use approx. I had continuous issues with apt-proxy, switching to approx solved all my problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you read both of these you should be able to figure out the difference.

[apt-proxy](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/administration_systeme/apt_proxy)

[apt-cacher](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/apt_cacher)

The apt-proxy is used to get packages from a remote machine. The apt-cacher is used to create a local proxy for packages.

Comment: If you read those, you will see both programs fulfill almost the exact same function.  The possibility I see is that apt-cacher does not cache the update files (the files fetched during an update), whereas apt-proxy does.

Comment: They do appear to serve the same function but are meant for different applications.

Comment: What are the different applications?  From what I have read they appear to fulfill exactly the same function, apt-cacher seems to be a apt-proxy replacement

Answer (score 1):

I have used mod-proxy in apache to provide this service in the past.  With proxy-cache, it seemed to work better than either of these solutions.

Squid with a cache may also do. There are the squid-deb-proxy package for caching, with squid-deb-proxy-client for cac autodiscovery of the cache.

Comment: Setting up a apache to proxy seemed to complicated, but makes sense that it worked the best since it has built in modules.  I see some pages with instructions, I may try that